# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient - in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ftp, apache-commons

Below is piece of code I have written to FTP a HTML file to a server. Although I get no errors in the code, when I execute the program I get the No Class Def Found Error on the FTPClient. I have downloaded commons-net-3.6-bin and import the following jar file into my project library 
commons-net-3.6.jar
commons-net-3.6-source.jar
commons-net-examples-3.6.jar

Not sure where to go from here.

```
String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");        
        String ImportSKU = projectPath + "Import SKU.HTML";
        File file = new File(ImportSKU);


          FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
          String filename = ImportSKU;


          // Read the file from resources folder.
          ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
          try (InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filename)) {

              client.connect("ftp://www.data.com");
              client.login("usedid", "password");

              // Store file to server
              client.storeFile(filename, is);
              client.logout();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
              try {
                  client.disconnect();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
```

Comment: If you defined the `FTPClient` class yourself, it might be helpful if you post its definition in your question... Or if you are importing it from somewhere, then show the import statement. Also, some information about the structure of your project would be useful- is the `FTPClient` class defined in the same project as this code?

Comment: This is the import statement - No code errors but fails on execution   import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;